# pooling data of mice from 2 independent experiment

Tags: dataset, pooling, mice

I am measuring inflammatory parameters in animals where i have 4 groups. Wild type mice treated/untreated and Knockout mice treated/untreated.
the aim is to see whether knockout mice have a significantly different response to treatment than wild type mice. I want to pool my mice from 2 different experiments to see whether I have a significant effect.
1) if my untreated wild type mice versus knockout mice are different to begin with then would it be better to show the fold change of one group mean compared to untreated mice mean in each genotype?
2) If So then how can i get statistical significance . Is there a way to randomly compare each mouse from the untreated group to each mouse from the treated group?